# Unable to add multiple groups in new-smbshare when ran through script

Tags: powershell, scripting, smb

When I run my script, i get the following error. However, when I run the New-SMBShare command directly on Powershell it goes through without issues. I tried passing the $groups as an array and a string, but keep getting the same error. I tried having it show the domain before the username and still same thing. I hope someone can help.

Please pardon my messy code, this is my first time scripting and first time with PowerShell as well.

Code:

```
<#
# Author:       Franklin Reyes
# File name:    sharedFolderCreation.ps1
# Purpose:      Facilitates shared drive creation process
# Version:      v1
# Date:         9/24/2020
#>

# Remote server where folder will be replicated **CHANGE THIS TO THE CORRECT SERVER HOSTNAME OR IT WILL FAIL**
$backupServer="WIN-R9HLL0ILD37"

# Counter for While Loop
$counter=0

echo ""
echo "*************************************************"
echo "The following drives are available:"
echo "*************************************************"

# Prints out a table of all the current drives on the system, along with the free space available and the drive's capacity.
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | 
        Select DriveLetter,
            @{Label="FreeSpace (In GB)";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1gb,2)}},
            @{Label="Capacity (In GB)";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Capacity/1gb,2)}},
            Label |
        Format-Table -AutoSize

# Prompts user to select the drive
$drive= Read-Host "Please select the drive you would like to use (Only enter letter and press the Return key)"

echo ""
echo "You have selected the [$drive]:\Share drive"
echo ""

# Prompts user to enter the name of the folder and stores value in the folderName variable
$folderName = Read-Host "Enter the Shared Folders name"

echo ""
$group=Read-Host "Enter the Security group to add to the Shared Folder"
$groups= "'"+$group+"'"
echo "Chosen groups are: $groups"

$path=$drive + ":\Shares\" + $folderName

# Checks to see that user input is not empty
while($groups -eq ""){
    echo ""
    echo "You did not enter a group"
    echo ""
    $group=Read-Host "Enter the Security group to add to the Shared Folder"
    $groups='$group'
    echo ""
}

# While loop allowing user to enter more than one group
while ($TRUE)
{
    $input= Read-Host "Would you like to enter another group? (Enter 'y' or 'n')"
    if ($input -eq "y"){
        $anotherGroup= Read-Host "Please enter group name"
        $groups=$groups + ",'" + $anotherGroup + "'"
        echo "Chosen groups are: $groups"
    }elseif($input -eq "n"){
        break
    }
    else{
        echo "You did not enter a valid response"
    }
}

# Checks if folder exists. If it does not, then it creates new folder under pre-specified path.
if (Test-Path $drive":\Shares\"$folderName -PathType Container){
    echo "The folder [$folderName] already exists!"
}else {
    New-Item $path -ItemType directory
    
    if (Test-Path $path -PathType Container){
    # Folder was created
        echo ""
        echo "*************************************************"
        echo "Success! The folder $folderName has been created on this server!"
        echo "*************************************************"
    
        echo ""
        echo "*************************************************"
        echo "Checking to see if the folder has been created in $backupServer"
        echo "*************************************************"
        echo ""
        
        # Checks up to 3 times to see if the folder has been created in $backupServer
        while ($counter -lt 3){
            $test=Test-Path \\$backupServer\$drive$\Shares\$folderName -PathType Container
            if($test -eq $True){
                echo ""
                echo "*************************************************"
                echo "The folder $folderName has been created on $backupServer!"
                echo "*************************************************"
                break
            }else{
                start-sleep -s 5
                $counter=$counter + 1
                echo "Trying again: Try #$counter"
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo ""
        echo "*************************************************"
        echo "Something went wrong. The folder [$folderName] was not created."
        echo "*************************************************"
    }

    <# If folder has not been created on $backupServer, the script will end and let user know that the folder was not
       created. The shares will also not be created for either local or remote server. If the folder is created, it will 
       continue to create the shares #>
    if ($test -eq $False){
        echo "File was not created on $backupServer"
    }else {         
        # Creates shared folder on this PC and gives read access to Everyone and full access to administrators
        New-SmbShare -Name $folderName"$" -Path $path -FullAccess $groups
        echo ""
        echo "*************************************************"
        echo "Creating share on [$backupServer]"
        echo "*************************************************"
        echo ""
            
        #Creates shared on backupServer
        $session=New-CimSession -ComputerName $backupServer
        New-SmbShare -Name $folderName"$" -Path $path -FullAccess $groups -CimSession $session
        Remove-CimSession -CimSession $session
    }   
}
```

Here is the output with the errors:

```
    PS C:\Users\freyes.FRANK\Desktop> .\runpowershell.bat

*************************************************
The following drives are available:
*************************************************

DriveLetter FreeSpace (In GB) Capacity (In GB) Label
----------- ----------------- ---------------- -----
                         0.02             0.05 System Reserved
C:                      26.94            49.45
                         0.08             0.49
D:                          0             0.06 VBox_GAs_6.1.10


Please select the drive you would like to use (Only enter letter and press the Return key): C

You have selected the [C]:\Share drive

Enter the Shared Folders name: testss

Enter the Security group to add to the Shared Folder: test1
Chosen groups are: 'test1'
Would you like to enter another group? (Enter 'y' or 'n'): y
Please enter group name: test2
Chosen groups are: 'test1','test2'
Would you like to enter another group? (Enter 'y' or 'n'): n


    Directory: C:\Shares


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name
----          ------------- ------ ----
d-----  9/28/2020   1:39 PM        testss

*************************************************
Success! The folder testss has been created on this server!
*************************************************

*************************************************
Checking to see if the folder has been created in WIN-R9HLL0ILD37
*************************************************


*************************************************
The folder testss has been created on WIN-R9HLL0ILD37!
*************************************************
New-SmbShare : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
At C:\Users\freyes.FRANK\Desktop\sharedFolderCreation.ps1:118 char:3
+         New-SmbShare -Name $folderName"$" -Path $path -FullAccess $gr ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1332,New-SmbShare


*************************************************
Creating share on [WIN-R9HLL0ILD37]
*************************************************

New-SmbShare : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
At C:\Users\freyes.FRANK\Desktop\sharedFolderCreation.ps1:127 char:3
+         New-SmbShare -Name $folderName"$" -Path $path -FullAccess $gr ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1332,New-SmbShare
    + PSComputerName        : WIN-R9HLL0ILD37
```

Comment: Why are you forcing single quotes around the group name with `$groups = "'"+$group+"'"`? Also the line `$groups = '$group'` will set `$groups` to the literal string `$group` and not the value of `$group` surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: I was forcing the single quotes as i thought it would need them when i pass them in the `New-SmbShare -Name $folderName"$" -Path $path -FullAccess 'test1','test2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are forcing single quotes around things. If you manually list strings then you would put the quotes around the strings, but if you are using a variable you do not need them. Try this instead:

```
$group=Read-Host "Enter the Security group to add to the Shared Folder"
[array]$groups= $group

# Checks to see that user input is not empty
while($groups -eq ""){
    echo ""
    echo "You did not enter a group"
    echo ""
    $group=Read-Host "Enter the Security group to add to the Shared Folder"
    [array]$groups=$group
    echo ""
}
echo "Chosen group is: $groups"

# While loop allowing user to enter more than one group
while ($TRUE)
{
    $input= Read-Host "Would you like to enter another group? (Enter 'y' or 'n')"
    if ($input -eq "y"){
        $anotherGroup= Read-Host "Please enter group name"
        $groups += $anotherGroup
        echo "Chosen groups are: $($groups -join ', ')"
    }elseif($input -eq "n"){
        break
    }
    else{
        echo "You did not enter a valid response"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the man. That did it. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Along with TheMadTechnician's helpful answer. Al those echo (aka Get-Alias -Name echo) are not needed at all. The PowerShell default is output to the screen unless you tell it otherwise. YOu coudl remove them all and the results woudl be the same. Also, a best practice is to not use Aliases in scripts. They are not guaranteeed to alwayas be there, and just cause more issues regarding readabilty and maintenance. If you openned this code in VSCode vs the ISE, VSCode would show all of these as a errors unitl you expanded them. So, would the PSScriptAnalyzer if you invoked that to scan your code.

Comment: See the PowerShell best practice guidance online. ['PowerShell Best Practices'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+Best+Practices%27&t=h_&ia=software)   ['PowerShell Best Practices' aliases](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+Best+Practices%27+aliases&t=h_&ia=web&iai=r1-0&page=1&adx=prdsdc&sexp=%7B%22v7exp%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22prodexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22prdsdexp%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22biaexp%22%3A%22b%22%7D) or un this command against your script.  [Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path 'D:\Scripts\ScriptUsingALiases.ps1']